# jquery check box groups issue

Tags: jquery

I have several identical check box groups within different divs like this ...

```
                                <h3 class="con_act_list">Activity</h3>

                                <ul id="activity">                                  
                                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="con_act_1" name="con_act[]" class="con_act" value="fabricate"/> Fabricate roofs<li>
                                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="con_act_2" name="con_act[]" class="con_act" value="buy-In"/> Buy-in roofs<li>
                                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="con_act[]" class="con_act" value="install"/> Install roofs<li>
                                </ul>
```

I am using class="con_act" to locate and set these check boxes to all selected OR  to 
all de-selectedbut NOT

I am using this function ...

$(".con_act_list").click(function() {

```
            $(this).parent().find(".con_act").attr('checked', !$(".con_act").is(':checked'));
        });
```

which works OK for one group (above) but not for other groups using the same class selector.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Just Use

```
$(this).next()
```

instead of

```
$(this).parent()
```

See this JSFiddle and tell if you want like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/cuAdP/

Comment: THanks. THat does not work either. Has same effect as .parent()

Comment: So exactly what do you want? when i click on first h3, all checkboxes should be checked or only those which are after that particular h3 should be checked?

Comment: when I click on first h3 only those which are after that particular h3 should be checked. BUT, when I click on another identical h3 elsewhere only those in the next group should be selected. There are multiple identical checkbox groups within different divs